# How to put a script in windows start so that it runs before log in

Tags: windows-7, boot, administrator

I need to put a script in Windows 7, so that it runs before the any user has logged on to the computer.  The script needs to keep on running after logging in by any user. So, the script runs as long as the computer is switch on...

Comment: A [scheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Run `gpedit.msc` and go to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts > Startup and add your script there.

Comment: somehow it does not work! could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @AliSyed You might have a problem with your script. Remember that if your script makes any reference to the logged-in user then it will fail (since nobody is logged in yet). Make a test batch script containing `echo %date% %time% >>c:\test.txt` and set that to run on startup. If the file is created then the problem is with your original script.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a batch file to execute your script, and drag the batch file to the system startup folder.

Comment: This answer lacks some content. If by "startup folder" you mean the folder in the Start Menu, then that batch file will only run after the user logs in.